# Hide Select item if another select item is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I'm trying to make a selector that will show options based off of what you have chosen in another select field. It looks like this:

```
           <select name="field2" id="field2" required="required">
                <option id="field2-1" value="os1">
                     os1
                </option>
                <option id="field2-2" value="os2">
                     os2
                </option>
                <option id="field2-3" value="os3">
                     os3
                </option>
           </select>
```

Then I have a second selector with these options:

```
           <select name="field3" id="field3" required="required">
                <option id="field3-1" value="dl1">
                     dl1
                </option>
                <option id="field3-2" value="dl2">
                     dl2
                </option>
           </select>
```

Basically what I need to happen is this: if os1 is selected in the first selector, then both dl1 and dl2 will be availible in the second selector.

If os2 or os3 is selected in the first selector, dl1 will be hidden, and only dl2 will be shown in the second selector.

I can't seem to find a solid solution for this, but I'm not the best at js, so hopefully one of you can point me in the right direction.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vanilla JS solution (no jQuery required) - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m7q3H/75/)

```
var selectOne = document.getElementById("field2");

selectOne.addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == 'os2' || this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == 'os3') {
        document.getElementById('field3-2').style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('field3-2').style.display = "block";
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. Out of curiosity, how would I make field3-1 selected, since field3-2 is disabled?

Comment: The problem is, even if it is selected, it doesn't appear to be. The other option is hidden like it's supposed to be, but it still says the other option is selected. You can go into the selector and select the only option, and that will fix it, but I'd like it to automatically do it. I found a possible fix using 
    document.getElementById("field3-2").selected = true; 
but it doesn't seem to work right with my styling.

Comment: I have a demo of what I'm talking about, but like I said, it's not working with my styling for some reason.

http://jsfiddle.net/m7q3H/124/

Comment: I don't see the problem - http://jsfiddle.net/m7q3H/155/ it shows the correct values whatever you select

Comment: I'll just give you the full code so you can see what's going on, because I can't seem to find the issue. I've also changed the second select to checkboxes. I need the second checkbox to disappear when mac/linux are selected. http://jsfiddle.net/m7q3H/163/

Comment: One more question, how would I go about deselecting the other box if one is selected?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could attempt this, but perhaps one of the simplest is to have two "template" SELECT elements that are hidden and then copy the html from these hidden SELECT elements to the #field3 SELECT element. I'll assume in this example that you're not using jQuery.

For example:

```
<SELECT id="template_1">
            <option id="field3-1" value="dl1">
                 dl1
            </option>
            <option id="field3-2" value="dl2">
                 dl2
            </option>
</SELECT>
<SELECT id="template_2">
            <option id="field3-1" value="dl1">
                 dl1
            </option>
            <option id="field3-2" value="dl2">
                 dl2
            </option>
</SELECT>
```

Then your javascript would be:

```
var field2 = document.getElementById('field2');
var field3 = document.getElementById('field3');
var template1 = document.getElementById('template_1');
var template2 = document.getElementById('template_2');
var os = field2.options[field2.selectedIndex];
if (os == 'os1') {
    field3.innerHTML = template1.innerHTML;
}
else {
    field3.innerHTML = template2.innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry, didn't realize the lack of `jquery` tag. Well, if you'd like to use jQuery, the code below will work:

```
$('#field2').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() === 'os2' || $(this).val() === 'os3'){
        $('#field3-1').hide();
    }
    else{
        $('#field3-1').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem with this code is it is destructive. Once you select os2 or os3 you can't get field3-1 back if they change their mind and select os1 again.

Comment: @wanovak Thanks, and sorry for the tag issue.

The issue is, even though the option is hidden, it's still looks like it's selected. Is there a way to force the other option to be selected?